# Android UI broken when run

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am facing very strange problem, though I am beginner level on Android. after designed my layout file, when i run this android project by using physical device then i actually not find expected UI.
Here is the Layout UI and it's XML code:-

Design:-

[image]

XML Code:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activities.DetailedActivity">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/detailed_img"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/detailed_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:title="Product Detailed" />

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        android:translationY="-50dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/detailed_img">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/detailed_name"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/amethysta"
                    android:text="Product Name"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="25sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/rating"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_toStartOf="@id/my_rating"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/amethysta"
                    android:text="4.0"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                <RatingBar
                    android:id="@+id/my_rating"
                    style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:isIndicator="true"
                    android:numStars="5"
                    android:stepSize="0.1" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/detailed_desc"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/amethysta"
                android:text="am following the standard example of how to add a RatingBar. To con The problem is that the number of stars doesn't seem to do anything a" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/amethysta"
                android:text="Price"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="21sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/amethysta"
                    android:text="$"
                    android:textColor="@color/purple_700"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/detailed_price"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/amethysta"
                    android:text="20"
                    android:textColor="@color/purple_700"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/add_item"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/plusicon" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/quantity"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="1"
                    android:textSize="30sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />


                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/remove_item"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/iconminus" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/add_to_cart"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/pink"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/mycart"
        android:drawableTint="@color/white"
        android:padding="14dp"
        android:text="Add To Cart"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/buy_now"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cardview"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".8" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buy_now"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_baseline_shopping_cart_24"
        android:drawableTint="@color/white"
        android:padding="14dp"
        android:text="Buy Now"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".8" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And this is my physical devices unexpected output:-

[image]

I don't understand why this output act like that and which is totally unexpected. how I resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `CardView` is not constrained by the buttons at the bottom the `CardView` will take space beyond those buttons. In the screenshot provided from a real device, it is clear that there is not much space to completely accommodate the contents in the `CardView` hence it will be pushed beyond the button. You need to add constraints to `CardView` to align it with the bottom button also you need to add a `ScrollView` if there is more content that the screen can't fully accommodate. Using this layout may improve the UI

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activities.DetailedActivity">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/detailed_img"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/detailed_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:title="Product Detailed" />

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        android:translationY="-50dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/add_to_cart"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/detailed_img">

        <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/detailed_name"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/amethysta"
                        android:text="Product Name"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="25sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/rating"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:layout_toStartOf="@id/my_rating"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/amethysta"
                        android:text="4.0"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />

                    <RatingBar
                        android:id="@+id/my_rating"
                        style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:isIndicator="true"
                        android:numStars="5"
                        android:stepSize="0.1" />

                </RelativeLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/detailed_desc"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/amethysta"
                    android:text="am following the standard example of how to add a RatingBar. To con The problem is that the number of stars doesn't seem to do anything a" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/amethysta"
                    android:text="Price"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="21sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/amethysta"
                        android:text="$"
                        android:textColor="@color/purple_700"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/detailed_price"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/amethysta"
                        android:text="20"
                        android:textColor="@color/purple_700"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/add_item"
                        android:layout_width="40dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/plusicon" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/quantity"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="1"
                        android:textSize="30sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />


                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/remove_item"
                        android:layout_width="40dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/iconminus" />
                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/add_to_cart"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/pink"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/mycart"
        android:drawableTint="@color/white"
        android:padding="14dp"
        android:text="Add To Cart"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/buy_now"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".8" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buy_now"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_baseline_shopping_cart_24"
        android:drawableTint="@color/white"
        android:padding="14dp"
        android:text="Buy Now"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".8" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```